# Woocommerce Cart price not matching the selected product price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, cart

I have few variation products on my site. As you can see in the image, the price of the product added to cart it 199 Rupees. But when added, the price shown in the cart above is 179! I checked in the admin panel, edited the product but everything is fine. What could be the issue? I have also tried updating wordpress and woocommerce.
I am using `<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?>` inside header.php to get the total price but it returns (TotalPrice - DiscountedPrice) when coupon is applied. I want to show only total price and exclude discounted price.
SO the problem is, if the coupon is applied, which is saved, the price shown in cart is the discounted price. But when you go to cart page, it adds the tax rate and applies coupon again!. How to fix this issue!
[image: Product Price is 199, but when added to cart, cart shows 179]

Comment: This looks off-topic to me or at best to broad. Please correct me if I am wrong, but the help you need is how to configure pricing within the Wordpress/Woocommerce plugin. Is that right?  Or are you programming the code itself?

Comment: @Trevor No it's not off-topic. I am using `<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>` to get the product total inside the header.php, which is returning total - discount price. May be I should update the comment

Comment: Where is the code for `WC()->cart->get_cart_total();`. You are not providing enough info for anyone to even start to help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as clearing the cache..

Woocommerce>>System Status >> Tools >> WC Transients >> Clear Transients